# Perl upload file using HTTP::Request

Tags: perl, post

I am using an existing framework to automate some apis.
This framework uses the HTTP::Request module. I need to write a script to upload a file.
I can do this using the HTTP::Request::Common module,but **NOT** with the Http::Request module.
But I need to use Http::Request only to get this done.
Below the code snippets:

**Using HTTP::Request::Common\This Works**

```
    $request = POST $uri,
    Content_Type => 'multipart/form-data',
    Content => [
    file => [$file]
    ]
    ;
    my $results=$ua->request($request ) ;
```

Using HTTP::Request\This does not work, I get an error missing file

```
    my $req = HTTP::Request->new("POST", $uri );
    $req->header(Content_Type => "form-data");
    $req->content('file=>$file');
    my $res = $ua->request($req);
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, there's a lot more going on in the `POST` method than just wrapping the constructor of an `HTTP::Request` object (see [here](https://metacpan.org/source/GAAS/HTTP-Message-6.04/lib/HTTP/Request/Common.pm#L25)).  Including at least the following (from a quick scan through the code):

- modifying the Content-Type header to be `multipart/form-data` with a random `boundary` to indcate where the file data starts in the request
- setting the Content-Disposition header to the appropriate value
- reading the file in and storing the contents of the file in the request body

I would highly suggest not trying to do all of the above manually but it's difficult to know your exact constraints and why you can't use `HTTP::Request::Common`.